# ng-click change value of a var

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to set ng-click to modify a var inside my controller.

I've tried to set ng-click to target the var mar.

```
<div class="Button" ng-click="mar = 'test-2';">
```

inside the controller.js i have this

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController', function EventController($scope) {

    //variables
    var mar = 'test-1';

}
```

So what i was hoping is to get var mar changed to 'test-2'; but, my html page just keeps displaying test-1.  is there a directive or a way to dynamically change var mar?

I do ***not*** want to have to setup a $scope.mar = 'test-1' and manipulate that. How can i do this?  Thank you.

Comment: Your update doesn't make sense. You want to be able to update a variable that is in your controller, but you don't want to have any type of relationship for that variable between your controller and your view? That's not really possible. Perhaps you could expand on your question to describe exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: so i want to dynamically change the variable so i can use it in a function. 

var tModel = modelService.models(mar);

would that be called like this? 

var tModel = modelService.models($scope.mar);

?

Comment: You haven't given us much information to go on, but I will conditionally say that yes, that would be the way to use two-way data binding in AngularJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare it on `$scope` and you have a typo

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController', function EventController($scope) {

    //variables
    $scope.mark = 'test-1';

}
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use `$scope` you have to assign `this` to a variable inside your controller. Here is a little example.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('EventController', function ($scope) {

    //variables
    var vm = this;
    vm.mar = 'test-1';

});
```

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="EventController as ctrl">
  <button class="Button" ng-click="ctrl.mar = 'test-2';">
    Click me!
  </button>
  <p>{{ctrl.mar}}</p>
</div>
```

If you want to use the variable inside a function on the controller you just use `$scope.mar` or `vm.mar`.

Comment: is there a way to call $scope.mark as a parameter in a function?  for example. 

        var tModel = modelService.models(mar);

Comment: You can just use $scope.mark inside that function. Are you using the controller on a state?